# Jquery mouse hover issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a slight issue with my mouse hover function on my images. When you hover over one image it's causing the hover over state to be active with all the images. [click here][1] Does anyone know where i have gone wrong??

//javascript

```
$(".tint").hover(function(){
$('.hover-hide').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

//HTML

```
<figure class="tint">
    <div class="hover-content hover-hide hidden">
        <a class="roll-over" href="#"><img class="img_hover" src="img/home-hover-bg.png" alt="hover"/></a>
    </div>
    </figure>
```

Comment: Do all of your `figure`s have the `tint` class?

Comment: Why do you need javascript for this? This can be done with css3.

Comment: You need to reference $(this). So something like `$(this).parent().find('.hover-hide').toggleClass('hidden')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(".tint").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.hover-hide').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`this`**](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/) to point the element that you are hovering.

```
$(".tint").hover(function(){
     $(this).find('.hover-hide').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

> In many object-oriented programming languages, this (or self) is a
>   keyword which can be used in instance methods to refer to the object
>   on which the currently executing method has been invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Find the div corresponding to that image:

```
$(".tint").hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.hover-hide').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```